# Tried to Run and print time -non-static variable cannont be referenced. I see whats happening but how do i fix?

Tags: java, object, static

I am beginning Object oriented and I wrote code to print the current time.
However I get an error saying non-static variable cannot be referenced.  I Understand whats going on but how do I fix this to print the time?

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    time time = new time();


time.GetHour();
time.GetMinute();
time.GetSecond();

time.print();
}
}
```

and my time class looks like

```
    public class time
    {
        public  int currentHour =0;
            int currentMinute= 0;
            int currentSecond= 0;


    public int GetHour()
    {
    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalHour = totalMilliseconds/1440000;
    long currentHour = totalHour %60;
    return (int)currentHour;        
    }   

    public int GetMinute()
    {   
    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalMinutes = totalMilliseconds/60000;
    long currentMinutes = totalMinutes %60; 
    return (int) currentMinutes;    
    }

    public int GetSecond()
    {   
    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds/1000;
    long currentseconds = totalSeconds %60;
    return (int) currentSecond;
    }

    public static void print()
    {
        System.out.printf("Current time is %d:%d:%d\n",currentHour, currentMinute,currentSecond);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the fields: `currentHour`,  `currentMinute`, `currentSecond` are local variables whose scope does not extend outside the methods.

And also you cannot refer to non-static methods or fields from a `static` method (print).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference to non-static class members (methods and variables) from a static method, since the non-static members are bound to a specific instance of the class, while static members aren't.

Either make the whole members non-static, and instantiate the class (create an object of it) or make the members accessed from the static method also static.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `main()` function

```
public class time
    {
        public int currentHour =0;
        public int currentMinute= 0;
        public int currentSecond= 0;


    public int GetHour()
    {
    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalHour = totalMilliseconds/1440000;
    long currentHour = totalHour %60;
    return (int)currentHour;        
    }   

    public int GetMinute()
    {   
    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalMinutes = totalMilliseconds/60000;
    long currentMinutes = totalMinutes %60; 
    return (int) currentMinutes;    
    }

    public int GetSecond()
    {   
    long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds/1000;
    long currentseconds = totalSeconds %60;
    return (int) currentSecond;
    }

    public static void print()
    {
        time t = new time();
        System.out.println("Current time is " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first static function or variable can be called without creating an object, that means a static function or variable is common to all objects you create. also static functions can only access other static variable and static functions, not the variable or function  that is not static, also non static functions can directly access static  functions and static variables...

In your code

```
public  int currentHour =0;
int currentMinute= 0;
int currentSecond= 0;
```

are not static variables so you got the error "non-static variable cannot be referenced"

hmm i have made modificatio to ypur code as follows

```
public class Time
{



public static int GetHour()
{
long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalHour = totalMilliseconds/1440000;
long currentHour = totalHour %60;
return (int)currentHour;        
}   

public static int GetMinute()
{   
long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalMinutes = totalMilliseconds/60000;
long currentMinutes = totalMinutes %60; 
return (int) currentMinutes;    
}

public static int GetSecond()
{   
long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds/1000;
long currentseconds = totalSeconds %60;
return (int) currentseconds;
}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.printf("Current time is %d:%d:%d\n",GetHour(), GetMinute(),GetSecond());
}

}
```

see here the print function is static, if we make all other function as static then it will work, 
or

declare

your variables as

```
public class time
{
    public static int currentHour =0;
    public static int currentMinute= 0;
    public static int currentSecond= 0;

     .....
     ....
    ....

    public static void print()
   {
    System.out.printf("Current time is %d:%d:%d\n",currentHour,   
    currentMinute,currentSeconds);
   }

}
```

here all three variables are static so can be accessed from the static function print

Comment: it works but it prints 0:0:0, obviously because they are static right?